# JavaMail get the URL of the Email - Gmail

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

I was wondering if it is possible to get the URL of an Email I am fetching via JavaMail.

In the Gmail Webapp I have e.g. an URL of the following type:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/14e0bbd1484a035a
```

I have build successfully an imap connection to the mailfolder and get the subject, body etc.

```
mailSubject = msg.getSubject();
```

Can I also get the URL from the Email with the same Message object?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can derive the URL from [Gmail unique message ID](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions?csw=1#access_to_the_gmail_unique_message_id_x-gm-msgid) (not to be confused with *IMAP unique ID*):

1. Retrieve Gmail unique message ID (MSGID) using a recent version of JavaMail (>= 1.5.2) - see the [sample code](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/gimap/package-summary.html).
2. Convert the ID to a *lowercase* hex variant (`1504408783077114714` becomes `14e0bbd1484a035a`).
3. Append it to "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/" to get the URL.